# Use same object form class in few independent functions

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

When trying to create my first 3D printer (with electronic and program) I was stopped with problem.

I create big library-class to work with my stepper motors.

My simplified code looks like:

```
#include "Config_TIMER.h"
#include "Stepper_Control.h"

SMotor StepperX(41,40); // Constructor to create new X stepper motor object)

void setup(){
StepperX.MaxSpeed = 11; // set value of object max speed
InitializeTimer();
}

void loop(){
StepperX.Move(500);  // move function 
}

ISR(TIMER5_COMPA_vect){

TimerTick(); // using one of Steper motor function
}
```

Now is my problem: All of my function need to use `StepperX.MaxSpeed` which was determined in `setup()` function (all other function use value of `.MaxSpeed` determined by constructor). Is there any easy trick to  connect all function - to use the same object?

Currently all my methods and variables are public.

Comment: Define a new object using an internal StepperX object?

Comment: Could you paste sample of this? I cant imagine how should it look like.